# jsp include is not working from subdirectories

Tags: jsp, include

I am not able to include a jsp file from a subdirectory. I have to include a file from include subfolder to a file in the test folder.

I tried this code

```
<%@ include file="../../include/file.jsp"%>
```

inside the file `../test/sample.jsp`

But I'm getting an error like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /all.jsp(132,1) File "/../../include/file.jsp" not found
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.processIncludeDirective(Parser.java:300)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseIncludeDirective(Parser.java:333)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:442)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1749)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:127)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:120)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:180)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:326)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

*Update*: I think the problem is related to tomcat.When I used to map the root folder as context in tomcat it was working and when I add root folder as a host,the problem arises.I want to use it as a host.

**Here in this tomcat config it doesn't work:**

```
<Host name="abc.test"  appBase="c:\abcd"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Context path="/" docBase="c:\abcd" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
 ..................................................................
...............................................................
</context>
</host>
```

**But it works in the following config**

```
<Host name="abc.test"  appBase="c:\abc"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

<Context path="/lang" docBase="c:\subdir" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
  ..................................................................
...............................................................
</context>

        <Context path="/" docBase="c:\subdir" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
  ..................................................................
...............................................................
</context>
</host>
```

ie, jsp include from subfolders works in http://abc.test/lang/ and  it doesn't work for http://abc.test
In both cases, the files from the same directory can be included

Comment: Try `<%@ include file="./../../include/file.jsp"%>`

Comment: I merged your accounts, so you should be able to edit the question instead of posting answers.

Answer (score 1):

I've found using the full path info (from the root directory) sans leading slash seems to work...

In other words, instead of

```
../../../Directory/file
```

I use:

```
FirstSubDir/SecondSubDir/ThirdSubDir/Directory/file
```

Including the leading slash (ie: `/FirstSubDir/Se...`) seems to cause the same issue as noted.

Answer (score 0):

Since the include directive takes a relative path you can start from the root of the site rather than use the ../ syntax. So you can try:  /include/file.jsp.

Comment: Thank you Vincent. I tried this also, but the problem is still there.Only change is that the error message has changed into org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /all.jsp(132,1) File "/include/file.jsp"

Comment: root/include/file.jsp,  root/test/sample.jsp,  root/WEB-INF/classes